# A double array not receiving double value

Tags: c++, debugging

I have this code (i developed that from FFT) and it seems alright, according to the Visual Studio... but then, when it arrives at the point that block[a][b] has to receive the value (even if it is not pow(), but just expo_final, for example), the values of block[a][b] are not going according to what I expect.

The source is here.

```
void twiddle_factor(float *d_isub_matrix)
{


    double block[THREAD_SIZE][THREAD_SIZE];
    float *d_osub_matrix = new float[THREAD_SIZE*THREAD_SIZE];
    int a,b,c,d,x,y,z;


    float sum_sines=0.0;
    double expo1,expo2,expo_final;
    float sum_cosines=0.0;
    float sum_sin[THREAD_SIZE][THREAD_SIZE],sum_cos[THREAD_SIZE][THREAD_SIZE];
    float angle=(2*PI)/THREAD_SIZE;

    //put into shared memory the FFT calculation (F(u))

    for(x=0;x<THREAD_SIZE;x++)
    {
        for(y=0;y<THREAD_SIZE;y++)
        {

            for(z=0;z<THREAD_SIZE;z++)
            {
                sum_sines=sum_sines+sin(d_isub_matrix[y*THREAD_SIZE+z]*(angle*(2*z)))+sin(d_isub_matrix[y*THREAD_SIZE+z]*(angle*(2*z+1)));
                sum_cosines=sum_cosines+cos(d_isub_matrix[y*THREAD_SIZE+z]*(angle*(2*z)))+cos(d_isub_matrix[y*THREAD_SIZE+z]*(angle*(2*z+1)));

            }
            sum_sin[x][y]=sum_sines/(2*THREAD_SIZE);
            sum_cos[x][y]=sum_cosines/(2*THREAD_SIZE);

        }
    }

    //getting the value!

    for(a=0;a<THREAD_SIZE;a++)
    {
        for(b=0;b<THREAD_SIZE;a++)
        {
            expo1=exp(sum_sin[a][b]);
            expo2=exp(sum_cos[a][b]);
            expo_final=expo1+expo2;
            block[a][b]=expo_final;
        }

    }
```

where ARRAY_SIZE and THREAD_SIZE are defined and their values are 64 (ARRAY) and 32 (THREAD).
I verified the values of sum_sines, sum_cosines, sum_sin[][], sum_cos[][],angle,expo1,expo2 and expo_final. Until the last one, everything is fine. They return some negative and positive values.
But I can't get the values of block[][]. Anyone knows what is going on?

Answer (score 4):

Here's your problem:

```
for(b=0;b<THREAD_SIZE;a++)
```